# Why is the author not doing a release on childController in the following segment of code?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, memory-management

I was doing a tutorial and the author shows an example however I am curious as to why he is not releasing childController at the end of the function. Any thoughts?

```
 -(void)tableView:(UITableView *) tableView
    accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    if (childController==nil) {
        childController = [[DisclosureDetailController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DisclosureDetailController" bundle:nil];
    }   
        childController.title=@"Disclosure Button Pressed"; //why this line?????
        NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
        NSString *selectedMovie = [list objectAtIndex:row];
        NSString *detailMessage = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"you pressed disclosure button for %@",selectedMovie];

        childController.message = detailMessage;
        childController.title = selectedMovie;
        [detailMessage release];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:childController animated:YES];

    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that childController is a field in this class and therefore (hopefully) releases it in the dealloc section.

He/She actually creates it only once.

**Edit:**

After a true nil check on childController the it gets a retain count of 1 and is assigned to the field. If the childController is not realeased prematurely this will be done only once during the lifetime of the instance of this whole class.

Comment: But with each tap on the tableView cell, would it not keep creating the childController increasing its retain count?

Comment: @jini: No. Presumably, the `childController` will only be `nil` the first time, where it will then be created in the second line using `alloc/init`. From then on, when that method is called, the `if (childController==nil)` will return NO, and the following line that creates the instance will be skipped.

Answer (score 1):

He's holding onto `childController` as an ivar, so presumably it will be released in the class's `dealloc` method.